# Should I implement ASP.NET MVC custom authentication via a DelegatingHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a client who needs to integrate custom authentication into a MVC website.

Where in ASP.NET MVC (or core) should I implement the following tasks:

1. Authentication
2. Conversion of JSON claims to ASP.NET claims
3. RBAC membership
4. ?????

Possible approaches:

- I could have a HTTP Post to `/controller/login`, create the auth cookie, and have the client use that [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31585768/328397)
- I could use a [HTTPHandler to validate incoming calls to each controller.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204257/how-to-implement-httpmessagehandler-in-web-api) .  One thing I like about this approach is that I can (or think I can) choose a different authentication policy per controller.
- I could use a [HTTP Module as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16904639/328397) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37434798/328397)

I'll be grateful for any assistance (or tips) you can provide in helping me building the right implementation

Comment: `custom authentication` Do you mean you want to use existing database with custom tables instead of ASP.Net Identity?

Comment: @Win it's a HTTPS POST of a signed Bitcoin address (zero knowledge proof) ... think JWT with different crypto.